# Resetting the Redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Does it make a difference when resetting the redux store on componentDidMount vs componentWillUnmount? I have seen dispatching a reset action on both lifecycle methods on different projects and wonder which one is better.

Comment: Well that depends entirely on your use case. There is no cut out answer to this question.

Comment: Can the store contain things before the first mount without an unmount having happened before? If yes, then on first mount is the place you'd reset it. Otherwise either one would work